# How to declare an AWS IAM Assume Role Policy in Terraform from a JSON file?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-iam, terraform-provider-aws

I'd like to provision for an AWS IAM Role its **Assume Role Policy** using Terraform. I already have the policy declare as a JSON file.

From documentation I understand that the module [aws_iam_role](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/iam_role) is what provisions an IAM Role but as I read from the note:

> The assume_role_policy is very similar to but slightly different than a standard IAM policy and cannot use an aws_iam_policy resource. However, it can use an aws_iam_policy_document data source. See the example above of how this works.

Which means I'm tight to the IAM Policy declaration according to the `aws_iam_policy_document` syntax (which itself requires me to manual convert into another format) but I don't see how I can import the policy from a JSON file instead to create the IAM Role I need - the reason behind is that the policy is quite broad and I'd like it to be in a separate JSON file.

Can anyone advise on how to declare an IAM Role with a Policy declared in a JSON file?

Comment: IAM roles have 2 parts: an assume role or trust policy (this allows things to assume the role, whether that's users or AWS services) and the permissions policy (what the role is able to do). Which of these do you have right now as a separate file?

Comment: it's you again, thanks for your help! :D So the field I was struggling to provide is `assume_role_policy` which from documentation page https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/iam_role seemed me to be only compatible with `aws_iam_policy_document` data. But I might have found a solution and I might declare the field in this way `assume_role_policy = jsonencode(file("${path.module}/my/path/my_json.json"))` - it was failing for me as I wasn't using jsonencode but now seems alright. Can you confirm too?

Comment: If that file is valid JSON then you shouldn't need the `jsonencode`. See https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/functions/jsonencode.html for what that function does (typically turning HCL maps into JSON). It would probably be easier if you edited your question to include a [mcve] that has this error and then someone would be able to tell you exactly where you went wrong.

Comment: hmmm probably I made confusion in my last comment and as you say the `jsonencode` is not needed (start approaching Terraform recently). I'll try posting an answer based on what you said too and correct me if wrong, code is definitely more readable than in comments

Comment: Here is a module I wrote to create policies, hope this helps: https://github.com/tomarv2/terraform-aws-iam-policies , you can see the examples of how to pass json.

Answer (score 5):

In the `aws_iam_role` documentation page there is no example that shows how to load a policy from a JSON file but this works for me:

```
resource "aws_iam_role" "my_role" {
  name               = "my_role"
  assume_role_policy = file("${path.module}/my/path/my_policy.json")
}
```